# srcset attribute in Gutenberg gallery blocks

Tags: block-editor

Gallery block are very useful to layout thumbnails. However, when I choose a columns layout (for example, four columns layout), the srcset for this thumbnail remains the same as a large image.

In other words, with a four columns layout, the thumbnails srcset come with:

```
sizes="(max-width: 768px) 100vw, 768px"
```

So, all thumbnails are built with the large images. For example, in this page: https://stage.margenesdelarte.org/productions/relato-de-salida-al-albergue-2018/

Is it possible to get something like this?:

```
sizes="(max-width: 768px) 100vw, 200px"
```

Further more, is it possible to set srcset up regarding the number of columns in the gallery block layout?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, setting the sizes based on the viewpoint size in the Gallery Block isn't possible as of this writing (quite frustrating, imho) :/

There's a couple outstanding tickets about this, notably:
https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/9620 and https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/13842